# Homogeneous of degree one functions that are a monotonic transformation of an additively separable function

Tags: functions, partial-differential-equations, convex-analysis, economics, homothety

Let $n>1$, and let $f:\mathbb{R}^n_{\ge 0}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}_{\ge 0}$ be continuously differentiable, concave, and homogeneous of degree one. Here, homogeneity of degree one means that for all $s\in\mathbb{R}_{\ge 0}$, and $x\in\mathbb{R}^n_{\ge 0}$, $f(sx)=sf(x)$.

And suppose that there exist continuously differentiable monotonic increasing functions $g:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}_{\ge 0}$ and $h_1,\dots,h_n:\mathbb{R}_{\ge 0}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ such that for all $x\in\mathbb{R}^n_{\ge 0}$:
$$f(x)=g(h_1(x_1)+\cdots+h_n(x_n)).$$

Must it be the case that there exists $a_1,\dots,a_n\in\mathbb{R}$ and $\rho,b_1,\dots,b_n\in\mathbb{R}_{\ge 0}$ such that for all $i\in\{1,\dots,n\}$, $h_i(x)=a_i+b_i \frac{x^{1-\rho}-1}{1-\rho}$? (Where, when $\rho=1$, we understand this as stating $h_i(x)=a_i+b_i\log(x)$.)

---

Note that by Euler's homogeneous function theorem:
$$g(h_1(x_1)+\cdots+h_n(x_n))=(h_1'(x_1)x_1+\cdots+h_n'(x_n)x_n)g'(h_1(x_1)+\cdots+h_n(x_n)).$$

Does this (differential equation) help?

Comment: Why can't you have $n=1$, $f(x)=x$, $g(x)=e^{x}-1$ and $h(x)=\log(x+1)$?

Comment: @Jeff OK I was missing an $n>1$ assumption! Thanks. You also remind me of another point that there's a $h_i(x)$ linear in $\log(x)$ (Cobb-Douglas) case which is strictly not included in what I've written here (it's a limit as $\rho\rightarrow 0$). I'll tweak the question.

Answer (score 1):

I cross posted this on economics.se as I thought there might be more chance of an answer there (at https://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/54600/are-homothetic-additively-separable-preferences-always-equivalent-to-ces/54601#54601 ).

The second to top "Related" question (https://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/6908/what-utility-functions-are-equivalent-to-additive-functions?rq=1) there contained a link to Ted Bergstrom's [Lecture Notes on Separable Preferences](http://www.econ.ucsb.edu/%7Etedb/Courses/GraduateTheoryUCSB/separabilitynotes.pdf), which answered this question in the affirmative.

The full proof is given in "Donald W. Katzner. Static Demand Theory. Macmillan, New York, 1970".